# Add javascript object on componentDidMount in rendered html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tracking

I want to add a javascript object into the template when the component did mount for tracking purposes. The object needs to render out like this:

```
var tracking = {
        pagename: 'page name',
        channel: 'lp',
        subSection1: 'section',
        pageidentifier: 'identifier'
      }
```

I have set a state object the object in the componentDidMount function but I can't seem to get the object to appear on the page.

Below is what I have called in the render function which :

```
<script>{`
      var dataLayer = ${this.state.tracking}
    `}</script>
```

This returns [object,object] but I need it to write out the object.

How do I go about doing this? I can't find any examples of doing this and it seems like such a simple thing to do but can't figure it out

Comment: if this is a global `var` why not attach it to the window? `window.dataLayer = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to append `script` tags is this:

```
componentWillMount() {
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.text= this.state.tracking;    
        document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

Though if this `object` is global, why not attach it straight to the window?
`window.dataLayer = this.state.tracking;`

Comment: I still get [object, object] outputted

Comment: well, this is an object indeed. what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I want to write var tracking = {
'key': value,
'key': value
}

exactly like that onto the page for tracking purposes

Comment: sorry but i don't understand what exactly do you want to do

Comment: I have a tracking object (dataLayer) that needs to changed when I change page for tracking to pick up what page. At this current point in time this answer isn't working as the tracking isn't picking up the object and there is also a js error - SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier but the js you provided is fine

Comment: The tracker runs on page load? If you are bulding a SPA then routing wont make the page to reload hence the tracker script wont run again to pick up the new data

Comment: yer i load the script for the tracking on page load. how do i go about doing tracking on a SPA?

Comment: Your initial question was about rendering a script, my answer covered it, i just suggested that you can attach a global object directly to the window if you must. about your other question on "tracking on a SPA" i think this deserve a new question post as this is not relevant for this question.

Comment: Okay i will try and ask another question

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to interact with a tracking function outside the scope of React you could also use a global function. In you index.html:

```
<script>
  document.MyTrackingFunc = function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
</script>
```

And in your componentDidMount function:

```
document.MyTrackingFunc(someData);
```

Comment: I get MyTrackingFunc is not a function if I dont load the homepage first and just reload on an internal page